# GStreamer warnings fist time its used

Tags: gstreamer

I'm running `GStreamer` in Raspbian Buster and I get a bunch of warnings the first time I use it, after a fresh install. This is not very problematic because is only one. However, I want to create a python binary using `pyinstaller` and each time I run the executable, I get the same warings. Any idea what is causing all these warnings? And how can I remove then, when using `gst-python`?

```
(hello_world:14518): GStreamer-WARNING **: 00:20:12.375: Failed to load plugin '/tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/libmmal_core.so': /tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/libmmal_vc_client.so: undefined symbol: mmal_status_to_string

(hello_world:14518): GStreamer-WARNING **: 00:20:12.376: Failed to load plugin '/tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/libmmal_util.so': /tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/libmmal_util.so: undefined symbol: mmal_log_category

(hello_world:14518): GStreamer-WARNING **: 00:20:12.386: Failed to load plugin '/tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/libmmal_vc_client.so': /tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/libmmal_vc_client.so: undefined symbol: mmal_log_category

(hello_world:14518): GStreamer-WARNING **: 00:20:12.399: Failed to load plugin '/tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/gst_plugins/libgstopenal.so': /tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/gst_plugins/libgstopenal.so: undefined symbol: _gst_debug_min

(hello_world:14518): GStreamer-WARNING **: 00:20:12.401: Failed to load plugin '/tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/gst_plugins/libgstmpeg2enc.so': /tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/gst_plugins/libgstmpeg2enc.so: undefined symbol: GST_CAT_DEFAULT

(hello_world:14518): GStreamer-WARNING **: 00:20:12.404: Failed to load plugin '/tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/gst_plugins/libgstlame.so': /tmp/_MEIwrkn0j/gst_plugins/libgstlame.so: undefined symbol: _gst_debug_min
```